# PhP documentator document return object types

Tags: php, zend-framework, netbeans, phpdoc

i have a \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager instance in my code and this function is being returned from a function wich is using the get function from it.

like:

```
$serviceManager->get('webuser')->IntelSenseHere()
$serviceManager->get('email')->IntelSenseHereLOL()
$serviceManager->get('horses')->IntelSenseHereHEEERE()
```

Now all thouse classes can be returned from this one call... How could i document what the function call is calling?

Because i have intel sense helper from nb 7.4 rc2 and it is pretty clever and reacts to the return document variable, i would like to specify what adapters it can return.

Is there a way to specify the classes it cann return??

like:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager $serviceManager
 * @param array $user
 * @return boolean, \Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager, horseAdapter...
 */
```

Is there a correct syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `ServiceManager::get($service)` will return the instance of the service you requested.

So, using one of your examples:

```
$serviceManager->get('webuser')->doSomething();
```

Is the same as:

```
$webUserService = $serviceManager->get('websuer');
$webUserService->doSomething();
```

You should therefore add the DocBlock annotation `@return` to the `webUser::doSomething()` method, **not** the `ServiceManager::get()`

The code completion will depend entirely on your IDE, however I believe this will work in Netbeans.

Comment: Perhaps "@return $this" is the docblock tag you want here, to indicate "fluent" behavior.

Comment: Aaaa damn formater made it look wierd. i corrected it.  It neeeds to get me functions IntelSenseHere